# Unicode issue when parsing html in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, unicode, lxml

I'm trying to parse a website's source to extract text inside using lxml library. Here is my code

```
import urllib2
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import html
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner

cleaner = Cleaner(page_structure = False)
htmlsource = cleaner.clean_html(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.verycd.com/").read())
htmltree = html.parse(StringIO(htmlsource.decode("utf-8"))).getroot()
listnode = htmltree.xpath("*")
for node in listnode:
  print node.text_content().strip().encode("utf-8")
```

When I run the code in interactive console, the result looks like this (dev environment)

```
VeryCD电驴大全 - 分享互联网
用户名：
        密码：记住我 


        免费注册
         |
        忘记密码？



            首页 |
            商城 |
            专题 |
            乐园 |

            社区 |
            电驴 |
            网页游戏 |
            网址大全
```

But in production environment, all unicode characters displayed incorrectly

```
VeryCDçµé©´å¤§å¨ - åäº«äºèç½
ç¨æ·åï¼
        å¯ç ï¼è®°ä½æÂ 

        Â 
        åè´¹æ³¨å
         |
        å¿è®°å¯ç ï¼



            é¦é¡µ |
            åå |
            ä¸é¢ |
            ä¹å |

            ç¤¾åº |
            çµé©´ |
            ç½é¡µæ¸¸æ |
            ç½åå¤§å¨
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

**EDIT**

Seems like I found the problem here. I think there is some thing wrong with lxml builtin GAE. If I don't use cleaner before parsing html, the output is fine.

```
# cleaner = Cleaner(page_structure = False)
# htmlsource = cleaner.clean_html(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.verycd.com/").read())
htmlsource = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.verycd.com/").read()
htmltree = html.parse(StringIO(htmlsource.decode("utf-8"))).getroot()
```

Comment: Never, ever use `print` inside a webapp!

Comment: I just try to run the code in interactive console, but I don't understand why the results between 2 environment are different

Comment: @NickJohnson Why not? This is a CGI app, so printing is perfectly normal. (Unless you meant don't print unicode -- true, but the author changed it to explicitly encode, which should be fine.) I've reproduced this and it seems like a bug in lxml on production (not the dev appserver). To simplify the example, any Unicode text passed to lxml.html.parse will come out encoded in UTF-8 and decoded as Latin-1, which is completely wrong. I will investigate this further.

Comment: I have filed a bug for this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7526

Comment: @mgiuca No, it's not a CGI app - it's just a snippet of code that uses `print`. For it to be CGI, it would have to, at a minimum, print headers.

Comment: Yes. @qazplm4ever I forgot to mention: you should be printing CGI headers, and because you are putting out UTF-8 bytes, you should explicitly set the encoding: `print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"; print`

Comment: The bug is fixed in App Engine now. Thanks again for bringing it to our attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: *This bug is fixed in App Engine, so the following work-around should no longer be necessary.*

I've accepted this as a bug in either lxml or App Engine. But you can work around it using `lxml.etree.parse` and `lxml.etree.HTMLParser` (note that `lxml.html` is a simple wrapper around these two):

```
import urllib2
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner

cleaner = Cleaner(page_structure = False)
htmlsource = cleaner.clean_html(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.verycd.com/").read())
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
htmltree = etree.parse(StringIO(htmlsource.decode("utf-8")),
                       parser=htmlparser).getroot()
listnode = htmltree.xpath("*")
for node in listnode:
  print node.text.strip().encode("utf-8")
```

That is:

- Create an HTMLParser object, explicitly setting `encoding='utf-8'`.
- Use `etree.parse` instead of `html.parse`; pass `parser=htmlparser` to `etree.parse`.
- Use `node.text` instead of `node.text_content()`.

This works around the bug by explicitly telling the HTMLParser to use UTF-8 encoding instead of having it guess (it guesses Latin-1 incorrectly).

Comment: Specifying encoding when creating an instance of lxml parser doesn't work on production. See http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7315 . So it seems there are a couple of bugs regarding lxml.

Comment: @Maxim I'm aware of that issue (thanks for reporting it). But as far as I can tell, while 'cp1251' and 'iso-8859-2' don't work, 'utf-8' or 'iso-8859-1' work fine. So my work-around should still work in production (at least it does for me).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just findout that if I don't clean the code before parse, everything is fine. `# cleaner = Cleaner(page_structure = False)
# htmlsource = cleaner.clean_html(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.verycd.com/").read())`

Comment: @qazplm4ever I don't see how not cleaning it is going to help. You've still got Unicode characters that aren't going to parse correctly. Also, don't you want to clean the HTML? It seems like by commenting out cleaning, you're not attacking the problem.

Comment: Oh, the reason it fixes the problem is because if you don't clean the HTML, it includes `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`. So that will work (but not for all web pages). I recommend that you clean it and use my solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most basic rules for dealing with text:

1. Decode the text into unicode as soon as you read it (you are doing this)
2. Do all of your processing in unicode (you are doing this)
3. Encode the text right before output.  You are not doing this.

Add an encode to your print statement and you should be fine.

Comment: Encode the text still output the same result. Actually, because I've changed the system default encoding to utf-8, so encode before output is not needed.